# bazel: fetch and unpack additional packages?

Tags: bazel

I try to build libedgetpu. This needs a lot of third-party packages (e.g. coral-crosstools).
Can I only fetch the packages and unpack them without building?
I need to patch a package before the build.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities. [Here](https://github.com/google-coral/libedgetpu/blob/master/workspace.bzl#L39) is the definition for that dependency.

```py
    maybe(
        http_archive,
        name = "coral_crosstool",
        urls = [
            "https://github.com/google-coral/crosstool/archive/" + coral_crosstool_commit + ".tar.gz",
        ],
        strip_prefix = "crosstool-" + coral_crosstool_commit,
    )
```

1. You can replace URL of the dependency with your fork (recommended, if change is huge and you want to maintain a fork) :

```py
    maybe(
        http_archive,
        name = "coral_crosstool",
        urls = [
            "https://github.com/my-fork-of-google-coral/crosstool/archive/" + coral_crosstool_commit + ".tar.gz",
        ],
        strip_prefix = "crosstool-" + coral_crosstool_commit,
    )
```

2. You can use [patch_args](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/repo/http.html#http_archive-patch_args) or [patches](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/repo/http.html#http_archive-patches) attribute of [http_archive](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/repo/http.html#http_archive) (recommended, if change is small)

```py
    maybe(
        http_archive,
        name = "coral_crosstool",
        urls = [
            "https://github.com/my-fork-of-google-coral/crosstool/archive/" + coral_crosstool_commit + ".tar.gz",
        ],
        strip_prefix = "crosstool-" + coral_crosstool_commit,
        patch_cmds = "rm some_file" # run that command
        # or
        patches = ["//cross_tool.patch"], # label to unix patch file

    )
```

3. Remove that entry, copy content of https://github.com/google-coral/crosstool repo to some directory and use it in that way (not recommended, but probably the easiest way, if you want to modify both workspaces in the same time)

```py
    maybe(
        local_repository,
        name = "coral_crosstool",
        path = "/path/to/the/coral_crosttol",
    )
```

These solutions are applicable, if you build libedgetpu directly. If you use libedgetpu as dependency in other `WORKSPACE`, then you have to apply any of these methods **before** you define the `libedgetpu`:

```py
http_archive(
    name = "coral_crosstool",
    strip_prefix = "some-prefix",
    urls = ["https://github.com/google-coral/crosstool/archive/6bcc2261d9fc60dff386b557428d98917f0af491.tar.gz"],
    strip_prefix = "crosstool-6bcc2261d9fc60dff386b557428d98917f0af491",
    patches = ["//cross_tool.patch"], # label to unix patch file
)

http_archive(
    name = "libedgetpu",
    strip_prefix = "some-prefix",
    urls = ["https://github.com/google-coral/libedgetpu/archive/refs/tags/release-frogfish.tar.gz"],
)
```

Thanks to the [maybe](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/2.2.0/repo/utils.html#maybe) wrapper the `libedgetpu` workspace will not define the `coral_crosstool` on its own.

Comment: SOrry, I can't comment, text ist too long. I added a answer instead

Answer (score 0):

first of all: thanks for your reply.

I updated the http_archive like you mentioned in 2)

But patch program can't find the file I like to patch.
I tried different paths, but noone worked.
At, the patch file "external/crosstools.diff" looks like:

```
--- a/coral_crosstool/cc_toolchain_config.bzl   Tue Jun  1 09:48:41 2021
+++ b/coral_crosstool/cc_toolchain_config.bzl   Tue Jun  1 10:23:06 2021
@@ -76,6 +76,8 @@
         "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/%d/include-fixed" % GCC_VERSION,
         "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
         "/usr/include",
+       "/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/%d/include" % GCC_VERSION,
+       "/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/%d/include-fixed" % GCC_VERSION,
     ],
     "armv7a": [
         "/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/%d" % GCC_VERSION,
```

But the result is:

> Error applying patch
> /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/pycoral-20210205/external/crosstool.diff:
> Cannot find file to patch (near line 1), old file name
> (a/coral_crosstool/cc_toolchain_config.bzl) doesn't exist,  new file
> name (b/coral_crosstool/cc_toolchain_config.bzl) doesn't exist.

What did I wrong?

Comment: Add `patch_args = ["-p1"],` . It is a normal procedure for patches generated by a git: the `a` and `b` don't exist, so you have to strip them from the path

Comment: It also does not work with "p1". Which path is the starting point?

Comment: Any patch created by `git format-patch <HASH>` should work with `-p1`. On the other hand I downloaded the https://github.com/google-coral/crosstool/archive/6bcc2261d9fc60dff386b557428d98917f0af491.tar.gz and there is no `cc_toolchain_config.bzl`, but there is `cc_toolchain_config.bzl.tpl`

Comment: The patch did not find both files.

Comment: Oh, and where do I have to place the diff file for the patch? Does it have to been put in a specific directory?

Comment: Look at some example https://github.com/ucichuck/mediapipe_wrapup/blob/978f1ae5611ede813b34b81c6883942e05e88bc0/WORKSPACE#L24

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I didn't understand which file I had to patch, cause a rule made "crosstools" from "coral-crosstools". Bazel is hell.....